# I want to block a set of IP's on my Linux machine. example a.b.c.d.0 to a.b.c.255..

Tags: linux, centos, ip-address, iptables

I want to block a set of IP's on my Linux machine. example a.b.c.0 to a.b.c.255.. I have tried the command (iptables -A INPUT -s a.b.c.0/8 -j DROP)
But this ends up blocking every IP address on my Machine. i just need to block a subset of IPs from a.b.c.0 to a.b.c.255. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `iptables -A INPUT -s a.b.c.0/24 -j DROP`?

Comment: Tried that, this 'iptables -A INPUT -s a.b.c.0/24 -j DROP' blocks nothing at all, lets all traffic through...